# How to extract coordinates from a coastline layer?

Tags: qgis, natural-earth

I have downloaded QGIS and the Natural Earth base maps. I'd like to somehow get a list of coordinates of a selected coastline.

I've got the 10m_coastline layer selected to what I want but can't see a tool or other table to join this to for coords?

Answer (score 2):

My assumptions:

1 - coastline is a linestring.

2 - access to coordinates in text format is okay.

3 - QGIS downloaded was 1.8.

Using QGIS 1.9 development but this should work on on version 1.8.

Select the lines you want the coordinates for. Open the layers context menu (right click):

1. select "Save Selection As"
2. choose Comma separated values. in the [OGR creation options](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html) Layer dialog add the following -- GEOMETRY=AS_WKT

This will output a csv with all attributes of layer. Geometry will be included as [Well Known Text (WKT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).

Sample output from a test polyline:

```
 WKT,id,
"LINESTRING (11278275.10722582414746312892908.136749047785997,11278312.186194457113743)",1
```

Comment: You can also select the appropriate row in the attribute table and copy it to the clipboard and it will copy WKT as well.

Answer (score 0):

The MMQGIS plugin allows exporting the coordinates of the line features as CSV file.

In a second step, import the CSV as delimited text file.